# Auto refresh sapui5 table after certain user specified interval

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a SAPUI5 table. What I want is to provide a text field, where user can enter time interval (like 3 mins), and the table will get refreshed automatically by itself after 3 mins. Moreover, if he provides new value (e.g. 8 mins), table will now get refreshed after 8 mins.

Can anyone give some ideas how can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As @sirion said, it depends a little on what table you have, how you want your scroll to behave and so on. I think it is inevitable that your table will "nudge" in some way or another if e.g. new lines get inserted in the table between refreshes or if some lies are deleted.

Nevertheless, I would say that the best option is to get the ListBinding from the table (as sirion said) and do a refresh on this binding:

```
onRefreshTriggered: function () {
    this.byId("myTable").getBinding("items" /* or "rows" */).refresh();
}
```

It might also be an idea to refresh the element binding for each row, then you would surely not have problems with the scrolling (but you will have problems in case a row is deleted or added).

```
onRefreshTriggered: function () {
    (this.byId("myTable").getItems() || []).forEach(function (oItem){
        oItem.getElementBinding(/* model name */).refresh();
    });
}
```

For doing the periodical triggering part, I would use the [sap.ui.core.IntervalTrigger](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.IntervalTrigger.html) class. It is fairly easy to use:

```
// e.g. in onInit:
   this._trigger = new IntervalTrigger(3 * 60 * 1000 /* initial interval */)
   this._trigger.addListener(this.onRefreshTriggered, this);

// in a separate method, e.g. as a input field change event
onIntervalChange: function(oEvent) {
    var iInterval = parseInt(oEvent.getSource().getValue(), 10);
    this._trigger.setInterval(iInterval * 60 * 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.setInterval` can be used to call functions at a specific time interval.
`window.clearInterval` can be used to terminate it.

Attach a change handler to your text, clear any existing intervals and start a new interval with the new time.

```
<Input change="onInputIntervalChange" />

onInputIntervalChange: function(oEvent) {
    var sIntervalInMinutes = oEvent.getParameter("newValue");
    var iIntervalInMinutes = parseInt(sIntervalInMinutes);
    var iIntervalInMillisec = iIntervalInMinutes * 60 * 1000;

    window.clearInterval(this._intervalId);

    this._intervalId = window.setInterval(function(){
        // refresh your table
    }.bind(this), iIntervalInMillisec);
}
```

Keep in mind that the first refresh will happen **after** the time interval has passed. If you want to refresh the table immediately when the user changes the value, call your refresh method directly before `setInterval`.

Comment: window.setInterval() returns a number which must be given to window.clearInterval() as the first argument in order to disable the interval.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of table you are using.
You can always just call oTable.getBinding("x").refresh(), with "x" being "items" or "rows". But that might lead to the table forgetting the scroll position if not everything is shown.

So the "real" solution would be to find out what slice of data is currently shown and then read exactly the same data from the back-end again. Using the read-method on the v2.ODataModel, the model stores the fresh data and updates the property bindings in the table as well.